# iOS: Open a Calendar app New Event screen with populated date

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, calendar

Is it possible to redirect a user to Calendar app New Event screen programmatically with populated start and end dates? I am aware of [Introduction to Calendars and Reminders](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/EventKitProgGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html), but that seems to be an overkill. I have also tried `calshow://`, but didn't seem to work either or I am couldn't find a correct scheme.

Comment: yes this can happen you can redirect it.

Comment: @NarendraPandey would you mind elaborating how?