# Choosing Calendar to add an iOS event

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, google-calendar-api

I'm trying to add events to the calendar in iOS devices, for now I've got to add an event to the `defaultCalendarForNewEvents` calendar, but what I want is to be able to choose a calendar that has already been created in which I want to add the event.

For example in the following capture it is seen that there is an iphone calendar and then there may be 1 or several gmail created

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

What I want to do is that **you can choose the calendar** in which you want to add the event, this calendar must be created earlier, not that the system chooses the calendar.

Any recommendations? Any examples?

P.D: I'm starting to code with [objective-c](/questions/tagged/objective-c) and [ios](/questions/tagged/ios)

Code to add events I'm testing and it works:

```
- (void) addEventCalendar: (Evento_DTO *) evento {
    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
    EKReminder *reminder = [EKReminder reminderWithEventStore:eventStore];


    event.title = @"Test Event";
    reminder.title = @"Test reminder";

    NSDate *cDate = [NSDate date];
    NSLog(@"current date  %@", cDate);


    /*NSDateComponents *startDateComponents = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
     [startDateComponents setDay:12];
     [startDateComponents setMonth:12];
     [startDateComponents setYear:2012];
     [startDateComponents setHour:12];
     [startDateComponents setMinute:18];


     NSDateComponents *endDateComponents = [[[NSDateComponents alloc] init] autorelease];
     [endDateComponents setDay:12];
     [endDateComponents setMonth:12];
     [endDateComponents setYear:2012];
     [endDateComponents setHour:12];
     [endDateComponents setMinute:18];
     [endDateComponents setSecond:20];*/


    //event.startDate = cDate;
    //event.endDate = [cDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:15.0];

    event.startDate = [cDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:((5*60*60) + (30 * 60) + 15)];
    event.endDate = [cDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:((5*60*60) + (30 * 60) + 30)];


    //event.startDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:startDateComponents];
    //event.endDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:endDateComponents];

    reminder.completionDate = [cDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:((5*60*60) + (30 * 60) + 10)];

    NSLog(@"startdate  %@", event.startDate);
    NSLog(@"enddate  %@", event.endDate);


    [event setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];

    //[reminder setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewReminders]];

    NSError *error = nil;

    [eventStore saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&error];
    //[eventStore saveReminder:reminder commit:YES error:&error];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, thank @NarendraPandey and @nehamishra for the help provided

I have given the solution to my problem, which will then put the solution in case someone can serve you.

I have created a method to obtain the available calendars that are local and those of gmail, the code is the following one:

```
- (NSMutableArray*) getCalendars {

    NSMutableArray *res =[[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
    EKEntityType type = EKEntityTypeEvent;
    NSArray *calendars = [eventStore calendarsForEntityType: type];

    for ( EKCalendar *cal in calendars )
    {
        if (cal.type == EKCalendarTypeCalDAV || cal.type == EKCalendarTypeLocal  ){
            NSLog(@"cal nombre:- %@ ", cal.title);
            [res addObject: cal];

        }
    }

    return res;
}
```

Then to show the list of calendars so that the user can select one and enter the events there, I found that Ihave to use an `Action Sheet`, although I have seen that it was deprecated according to some forum comments Of StackOverflow, so I used `UIAlertController`, being as follows:

```
NSMutableArray* cals =  [self getCalendars];

if([cals count] > 0){//Comprobamos que existan calendarios

   UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController   alertControllerWithTitle:AMLocalizedString(@"calendar_dialog_info", @"")
          message:nil
          preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleActionSheet];

   for ( EKCalendar *cal in cals )
   {
         UIAlertAction *calAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle: cal.title
         style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {

         NSLog(@"You pressed button %@ ", cal.title);

         [self descargarCalendario:  cal];
          }];

          [alert addAction:calAction];
   }

   UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                                         actionWithTitle:AMLocalizedString(@"cancelar", @"")
               style:UIAlertActionStyleCancel
               handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
               {
                    [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

               }];

         [alert addAction:cancel];

         [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
}else{
    NSLog(@"No hay calendarios");
}
```

Where the `[self downloadCalendario: cal];` function is responsible for downloading some events from a web service and adding them to the chosen calendar.

Resulting in the following view to choose the calendar:

[image]

And the code to add the event to the selected calendar is:

```
-(void)addEventOnCalendar: (EKCalendar *) cal{

    EKEventStore *store = [EKEventStore new];
    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (!granted) {
            return;
        }
        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
        event.title = @"Test";

        NSDate *cDate = [NSDate date];
        event.startDate = [cDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:((5*60*60) + (30 * 60) + 15)];
        event.endDate = [cDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:((5*60*60) + (30 * 60) + 15)];

        //event.calendar = [store defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
        event.calendar = [store calendarWithIdentifier: cal.calendarIdentifier];

        NSError *err = nil;
        [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];

    }];
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Event Successfully added " delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];

}
```

I hope it helps somebody.

Answer (score 1):

Try this by creating new calendar.

```
 -(EKEvent*)createEvent:(EKEventStore*)eventStore{
        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
        event.title = @"New Event";

        event.startDate = [NSDate date];
        event.endDate =[NSDate date];

        event.location=@"Location";
        event.allDay = YES;
        event.notes =@"Event description";

        NSString* calendarName = @"Calendar";
        EKCalendar* calendar;
        EKSource* localSource;
        for (EKSource *source in eventStore.sources){
            if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeCalDAV &&
                [source.title isEqualToString:@"iCloud"]){
                localSource = source;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (localSource == nil){
            for (EKSource *source in eventStore.sources){
                if (source.sourceType == EKSourceTypeLocal){
                    localSource = source;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        calendar = [EKCalendar calendarForEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent eventStore:eventStore];
        calendar.source = localSource;
        calendar.title = calendarName;
        NSError* error;
        [eventStore saveCalendar:calendar commit:YES error:&error];
        return event;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Hope it will work.
Let me know if you have any query.

Comment: Thank you very much I will try this to see if it serves me, and I will tell you if it serves me

Comment: I try your code and works fine to create a new calendar, but I would like to be able to choose a calendar that is already created and add events in that calendar, maybe my description of the problem was not clear or induces confusion, now I will edit it

Comment: Yes in Second Screenshot you can see. You can select calendar from available calendar.

Comment: I have tried your code and I have not got any window to choose the calendar, maybe I have not put some necessary code. Excuse me but I'm pretty new to the iOS programming.

Comment: okk so just check out my answer at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40525194/ios-open-a-calendar-app-new-event-screen-with-populated-date/40525479#40525479

Answer (score 1):

```
-(void)addEventOnCalendar{
    EKEventStore *store = [EKEventStore new];
    [store requestAccessToEntityType:EKEntityTypeEvent completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error) {
        if (!granted) {
            return;
        }
        EKEvent *event = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:store];
        event.title = @"What ever You want to save as your event";
        event.startDate = selectedDate;

        event.endDate = selectedDate1;

        event.calendar = [store defaultCalendarForNewEvents];
        NSError *err = nil;
        [store saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent commit:YES error:&err];

    }];
    UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Message" message:@"Event Successfully added in Calender" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer